# onClick return function and GeoLocation

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am creating a webpage for uploading file to the server. before uploading the file my webpage collects geolocation of the user. 
but function "return GetLocation()" is not working. my code is bypassing the javaScript code for obtaining GeoLocation.
Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
    var x = document.getElementById("LocationStatus");

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Browser not supported!";
            return false;
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        document.cookie="lat="+position.coords.latitude+"lon="+position.coords.longitude;
        return true;
    }
    function error(msg) {
      var s = document.querySelector('#status');
      msg = msg.message ? msg.message : msg; 
      s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
      s.className = 'fail';
      return false;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="my_file" />
    <button type="submit" onclick="return getLocation()">Upload File</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call a function by mentioning `return` in the statement.

**Change your code to**

```
<button type="submit" onclick="callFunction();">Upload File</button>
```

Now you `getLocation()` function will be called.

And in your code you are just calling the main function but the functions in it aren't called so

Try calling them as well

```
<script>
function callFunction(){
getLocation();
showPosition(position);
error(msg);
}
 var x = document.getElementById("LocationStatus");

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Browser not supported!";

        }
         return false;
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        document.cookie="lat="+position.coords.latitude+"lon="+position.coords.longitude;
        return false;
    }
    function error(msg) {
      var s = document.querySelector('#status');
      msg = msg.message ? msg.message : msg; 
      s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
      s.className = 'fail';
      return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: same issue. without getting the location of the user the form moves to upload.php.

Comment: Check out my edited code this is a correct syntax but you might get problem with your arguments `position` and `msg` in the code.

Comment: its still moving to upload.php without asking for permission for location.

Comment: Ok i got the whole thing sorted out look first here the return is necessary because you have given an `onclick` event to the `button[type = submit]`,or else it wouldn't have been required,my mistake sorry for this.And secondly you should set the return true in the function to be called by this  `button[type = submit]`.Now check out my edited answer.

Comment: did not work. file saved without asking for location.

Comment: Now it will call all the functions.

Comment: And you do not return in the `else{}` statement i have changed it too.

Comment: have a look at the working link here https://jsfiddle.net/t79zogr6/.

Answer (score 0):

**Use onsubmit="getLocation()" instead of onclick and use it on form element**

```
<form  method="POST" onsubmit="getLocation()" action="upload.php" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="my_file" />
<button type="submit">Upload File</button>
</form>

 function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Browser not supported!";
        return false;
    }
}
```